# What can we say about a group $G$ if for all $a,b,c,d$ in the group, $ab=cd\implies ba=dc$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose that, for elements $a, b, c, d$ of $G$, we have $ab = cd \implies ba = dc$. Can we derive anything from this, or are there any conditions that result in such a property? I.e. what does it imply, and what might imply it?

For example, this seems to be true of the dihedral group. And obviously it is true for any abelian group.

Note: The phrase "commute via equality" is just something I used to describe this and is probably not a standard description.

Comment: what does this mean? for all a,b,c,d \in G: if ab=cd then ba=dc?

Comment: @miracle173 Yes, you could say that is the original question. Thanks to an answer below, I now realize this means that the group is abelian. So maybe a more interesting question would have been "for some elements $a, b, c, d$" or "for non-identity elements $a, b, c, d$", but I won't change the question now since there is already an answer.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer and if you want you can open a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is equivalent to the group being abelian; pick $d = e$ (identity). 
Then for arbitrary elements $a, b \in G$, denote the product $ab = c$.
Then by the assumption $ba = c$ too, so that $ab = ba$.

Comment: Oh ok, so I must be wrong when I said that the property holds for the dihedral group. I'll try to figure out where my reasoning went wrong...